# Unable to install Ubuntu after graphics drivers(NVIDIA) update failure in Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual machine

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, tensorflow

I had Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my Virtual Box/Win10 host(graphic card: Nvidia M1200 + Intel xx) and it worked fine until I was trying to install tensorflow-gpu-1.13.0 and updating Nvidia driver using this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

It didn't seem to work, but I continued with the following commands anyways just to see what happens

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

Then it got into a login loop after a reboot, where it logs you in then logs you out immediately so you're stuck at login GUI forever. After trying everything, I finally gave up and tried to reinstall Ubuntu. But this time I can no longer install it, it gives error:

```
errno 5 - input/output error
```

I ran a memory diagnose and it returned fine, checked the disks using `chkdsk c: /f /r` and it returned fine. The .iso image should be good because it worked before. But on Ubuntu startup (before installation), the log says

```
squashfs error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x2811aa6d
squashfs error: zlib decompression failed, data probably corrupt
...
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved the problem.

1. Delete all the temp files (search for `%temp%` in Windows Menu Search Box) then empty trash bin.
2. Restart laptop/pc